# How Do I Change Pi-Hole's URL Path?

Tags: raspbian, web-server, pi-hole

How do I change [pi hole](https://pi-hole.net/)'s URL?

It's currently `10.0.0.20/admin`.

I want to use the `/admin` path for something else but couldn't find a way to change Pi-Hole's path to something else.

Comment: It doesn't look to me as if this is supposed to be changed. If you head for their Github page and [search for 'admin'](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=admin) it pulls up half a dozen different entries in half a dozen scripts. That suggests that the 'admin' value has been baked in pretty solidly - I think it might prove tricky (certainly not impossible, but liable to a few failures) to prune out all the instances and replace them with something else that worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many ways that you could do this, but the easiest is to change the port that pi-hole is using.

Edit `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and change the line that says [`server.port = 80`](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/48f9a61ff0f577b61c6e9129ed59f13ff242678d/advanced/lighttpd.conf#L29) to use some other port number such as `8080`. Then restart LigHTTPD using `sudo service lighttpd restart`, and you will be able to access the pi-hole administrative interface at http://10.0.0.20:8080/admin.

Note that if you ever re-run the pi-hole installer, it will reset this value back to the original port 80.

Comment: This may have changed but the lighttpd.conf file is now at `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`.  That said if you want to make the change last through a pihole update you should put it in a new file called `/etc/lighttpd/external.conf`.

Answer (score 11):

This is another way to change its port and the benefit is that it won't get reset any time you reconfigure pi-hole or update it.

Add `server.port := 8000` or your desired port to `/etc/lighttpd/external.conf` then restart. Then restart lighttpd using `sudo systemctl restart lighttpd`, and you will be able to access the pi-hole administrative interface at http://localhost:8000/admin.

Comment: Weirdly this causes an error on a restart and lighttpd fails to launch.

Comment: I think you may have added it like this-  server.port = 8000 instead of this-   server.port := 8000 , notice the colon? Only after omitting the colon am I able to reproduce the error at launch. Could you clarify if you did that?

Comment: I wonder why `:` is needed here, whereas in `lighttpd.conf` not.

Comment: @user3123159 It's the replace syntax: `replace  : NAME := VALUE    (replace/overwrite earlier value) (since 1.4.46)` : https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_configuration

Comment: In my new installation of Raspbian and PiHole, it doesn't appear that `/etc/lighttpd/external.conf` is parsed by lighttp at all. Instead of that path I used `/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/external.conf` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason putting the server.port in external.conf results in an error on restart.
Changing it in lighttpd.conf works fine.

To get rid of the /admin in the URL one could create a link in the /html folder.
ln admin pi-hole -s

Together with the port change it could look like this
http://op:88/pi-hole/
(well the /admin path would still be there, it would just be for cosmetics)

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda sad there isn't a more straight forward answer to this. I'd like to do the same as the OP but changing ports negates the point for my use case. The issue is the URL being a common exploit attempt. I know this is a pi-hole feature request rather than a pi related issue...but you should be able to denote your admin URL so you can put a device on the front line and at least remove the obvious things scripts and worms look for.

Basically:

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/admin /var/www/html/r4nd0N4m3
```

Then

```
sudo vi /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (find and replace admin with r4nd0N4m3.)
```

Restart the service and maybe your browser if it's caching. Repeat on updates or anything that overwrites the changes...

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I just did this... by changing the admin page from /myip/admin to /myip/anything

It's not as straight forward, since the "admin" path are hardcoded. You need change the admin path as well as modify Pi-hole's scripts to make it work.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache2 server. However, I believe most server are similar.

1. Change webpage location:

   `sudo mv /www/html/admin /www/html/anything`
2. restart apache2 server

   `sudo service apache2 restart`
3. Go to pi-hole script directory

   `cd /opt/pihole`
4. Modify any instance of `/www/html/admin` into `/www/html/anything`
   I found following files contains this string:

```
  uninstall.sh
  updatecheck.sh
  update.sh
  webpage.sh
```

Just `cat *.sh | grep html/admin` to find any remaining instance

5. Profit!